# Celery beat doesn't run periodic task

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have task

```
class BasecrmSync(PeriodicTask):
run_every = schedules.crontab(minute='*/1')

def run(self, **kwargs):
    bc = basecrm.Client(access_token=settings.BASECRM_AUTH_TOKEN)
    sync = basecrm.Sync(client=bc, device_uuid=settings.BASECRM_DEVICE_UUID)
    sync.fetch(synchronize)
```

And celery config with db broker

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
BROKER_URL = 'django://'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
```

I run

```
celery -A renuval_api worker -B --loglevel=debug
```

But it doesn't run task...
Also I've tried run by

```
python3 manage.py celery worker --loglevel=DEBUG  -E -B -c 1 --settings=renuval_api.settings.local
```

But It uses amqp transport and I can't understand why.

Comment: Have you added your task in CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE in settings.py http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#beat-entries

Comment: I have added schedule in task property run_every. http://joxi.net/MAjbQ87hvGBnKA

Answer (score 1):

I run a separate process for the beat function itself. I could never get periodic tasks to fire otherwise. Of course, I may have this completely wrong, but it works for me and has for some time.

For example, I have the celery worker with its app running in one process:

```
celery worker --app=celeryapp:app -l info --logfile="/var/log/celery/worker.log"
```

And I have the beat pointed to the same app in its own process:

```
celery --app=celeryapp:app beat
```

They are pointed at the same app and settings, and beat fires off the task which the worker picks up and does. This app is in the same code tree as my Django apps, but the processes are not running in Django. Perhaps you could run something like:

```
python3 manage.py celery beat --loglevel=DEBUG  -E -B -c 1 --settings=renuval_api.settings.local
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I told that manage.py way require amqp. I can't understand why.

Comment: Some questions: 1) You keep mentioning AMQP. Are you running RabbitMQ? 2) Are you checking your log files under /var/log/celery?

Comment: No, I don't use rabbit. But when I try run celery via manage.py it uses amqp as transport(and raise error "Can't connect"). There is no errors in log....

Comment: What broker are you using instead of RabbitMQ?

Comment: BROKER_URL = 'django://'

Comment: I believe your celery settings are not being read, and so celery is using defaults. This is discussed here: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1655

If this is not working, the periodic beat stuff will not work, much less anything else related to celery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109195/discussion-between-guerry-and--).